# How can I non-interactively squash git commits with *nearly* the same commit message?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a GitHub action which does some stuff and commits some changes to the repository. The commit message it makes it something like "$NAME updated to $VERSION", but I can change that to something else if required going forward.

I can squash the existing commits interactively now, so there will just be single previous commit for every $NAME, but how do I make this GitHub action automatically squash the previous commit with the same $NAME, but different $VERSION?

While I can change the commit message to start with fixup! or squash! if needed, I would like to keep the $VERSION part, which would be unique to every $NAME commit.

^^ Up is more recent

```
Update grapes to v3.2    <---new commit
foo commit
bar commit
baz commit
Update mitshubishi to v2
apple commit
Update grapes to v2.34   <---needs to be squashed into new commit
bananas commit
pear commit
Update ford to v3
```

The GitHub action will make another commit with the message `"Update grapes to v3.2"`, but I then want it to move `"Update grapes v2.34"` up under this most recent commit and squash it into the new commit.

If it is not possible with partially different commit message, I could replace $VERSION with "latest", but would prefer not to.

Comment: I think it might help if you provided an example of what your commits look like before, and what you'd like them to look like after, the action is run.

Comment: @TTT I've added more information. The end result would be as above, but without the squashed commit.

Comment: OK. I think I understand what you're asking, though it seems strange. If I understand correctly you only want to have a single commit per type. This means you don't care about the history of each type, but instead only the most current state. The commits you do have wouldn't end up being related to each other, so it wouldn't be much different than having 1 branch per type, each with only one commit that you keep amending. In fact, if you did that it would be conceptually easier to manage than interactive rebasing each time and parsing out the commits to reorder and squash.

Comment: Thanks for taking time thinking about this. Your branching idea seems confusing for my understanding. I think there is a way to `--autosquash` when the commit message starts with `!squash`, but not sure if that would work when there are other $NAME types which shouldn't be squashed as well. Also, I think that would require renaming the new commit with that prefix after the squashing, but I'm not sure as I've never used this. And I don't think I can use different $VERSION numbers? These are the questions I hope to get answered.